# Get specific values from list python

Tags: python

I want to get all the values for the key 'id' in data (without all the other extra information, simply just all of the id values (e.g 60220611, 76744679)

```
import requests
import json
import urllib, json
import time

proxies = {"http": "http://176.9.75.42:3128",
           "http": "http://88.198.50.103:8080"}

user_id = 4913866


def jprint(obj):
    text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    print(text)


user_id = 367
URL = f"https://badges.roblox.com/v1/users/{user_id}/badges"
data = []
payload = {"limit": 100, "sortOrder": "Asc"}
resp = requests.get(URL, params=payload)
resp.json()
blob = resp.json()
data.extend(blob["data"])
cursor = blob["nextPageCursor"]

while cursor is not None:
    payload.update({"cursor": cursor})
    resp = requests.get(URL, params=payload, proxies=proxies)
    blob = resp.json()
    data.extend(blob["data"])
    cursor = blob["nextPageCursor"]
    data.append([cursor])
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
import json
import urllib, json
import time

proxies = {"http": "http://176.9.75.42:3128",
           "http": "http://88.198.50.103:8080"}

user_id = 4913866


def jprint(obj):
    text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    print(text)


user_id = 367
URL = f"https://badges.roblox.com/v1/users/{user_id}/badges"
data = []
payload = {"limit": 5, "sortOrder": "Asc"}
resp = requests.get(URL, params=payload)
resp.json()
blob = resp.json()
data.extend(blob["data"])
cursor = blob["nextPageCursor"]

while cursor is not None:
    payload.update({"cursor": cursor})
    resp = requests.get(URL, params=payload, proxies=proxies)
    blob = resp.json()
    data.extend(blob["data"])
    cursor = blob["nextPageCursor"]
    data.append([cursor])
    print(data)

# iterate over data list and get the key.
id_list = [each['id'] for each in data]
print(id_list)
```